# grub being filled with "ehci-pci resume error" upon resuming from sleep

Tags: suspend, chromebook, acpi

Using a Toshiba Chromebook, with Ubuntu 16.04 installed, everything is fine until I close the lid to put it into sleep mode. Once I open the lid, this happens in the boot log

```
<snip>
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel:  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: CPU1 is up
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: pci_raw_set_power_state: 39 callbacks suppressed
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: PM: noirq resume of devices complete after 92.898 msecs
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: PM: early resume of devices complete after 0.809 msecs
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: ath: phy0: ASPM enabled: 0x43
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: rtc_cmos 00:03: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: usb usb1: root hub lost power or was reset
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: port 3 resume PLC timeout
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: port 1 resume error -19
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: usb 2-3: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: ata1: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: usb 2-4: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: usb 2-4: device firmware changed
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: PM: resume of devices complete after 699.613 msecs
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: PM: Finishing wakeup.
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: Restarting tasks ... 
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: port 1 resume error -19
Jun 06 19:04:53 Waffle kernel: done.

<snip>
```

The error in question is of course

```
Jun 06 18:40:16 kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: port 1 resume error -19
```

Soon after the wake is complete, the grub log is just filled with the error, occasionally printing something like "connect bounce failed" before switching to

```
Jun 06 18:40:16 kernel: ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: port 2 resume error -19
```

Then after a few seconds switching back to "port 1".

I just don't know what to make of this or what is causing the problem.

Also, the computer is quite slow at shutting down, don't know if its related or not.